# Mandrill for outgoing mail in a mail client

Tags: mailchimp, email, mandrill, transactional-email

I'm using Mandrill for my transaction email needs and it works great. Unfortunately very often when I send emails via my email client the emails go to the recipients spam folder.

Is there a way to use Mandrill for outgoing emails via a mail client (such as Apple Mail or Thunderbird)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mandrill's Outgoing Server (SMTP) Setting in the MailClient of your choice.

[SMTP Settings](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582147-How-to-Send-with-PHPMailer)

- Outgoing Server: smtp.mandrillapp.com
- Outgoing Server Port: 587
- Auth Required: True
- TLS: True
- Username: complete email-id

Changing the MailClient is not probably going to mark your mails as legitimate.

There are multiple reasons for mail going to spam folder of recipient like:

- Mandrill's IP address got blacklisted in recipient's SMTP (MX) server.
- Your mail contains some links or content which is recognized as suspicious and hence recipient marks such mails as spam.

In short, mail getting marked as spam depends upon:

- Sender SMTP server's reputation.
- Sender's mail content.
- Receiving SMTP (MX) (i.e recipient's) server business logic for mail classification.

Comment: I have tried using Mandrills SMTP for outgoing mail. The email comes up in my mandrill dashboard but it gets a "Rejected" status with "Reject Reason: unsigned". Any ideas how to fix that? @sameerkn

Comment: Since I do not have Mandrill's account, so you can check your account [Server Settings](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582247-About-Domain-Verification).  DKIM and SPF should be enabled.